# How to accomplish SQL Server 2012+2014 high availability

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

(Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128204/how-to-accomplish-sql-server-20122014-high-availability))

Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing, but I can't see how I can do this.

I have two servers:

1. Server A (has SQL Server 20**12** installed)
2. Server B (has SQL Server 20**14** installed)

Server A provides an API via IIS. The code both inserts and gets data from the database depending on the API call.

Server B does exactly the same for its local database.

I would like to have it so that the two databases are consistent copies of each other. I do believe this is what HA accomplishes.

So a load balancer, for example, might direct API calls to A sometimes, and B sometimes, but the data needs to be consistent either way.

I found some documentation on HA for SQL Server 2012, but not on how to do this for a mixed environment of 2012 and 2014.

Any help or pointers to documentation would be great! Thanks.